# How to show a flowdocument in multiple pages like Word?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, flowdocument

I have an project that is much like MS Word and needs to display and Edit a range of pages with contains Rich text and want to show this content onscreen in multiple rich-text-box controls that are stacked vertically and scrolled to create the effect of document flow.

Also i would like the content to flow automatically between the controls and overflow to the next control etc.

is there any other way around if that is not possible ?